# Grails XML Bad Request

Tags: xml, rest, grails, get

I want to get a XML document from a webservice: http://api.sandbox.inrix.com/Traffic/Inrix.ashx?action=FindRoute

When I visit this site in my browser, I get a XML-Tree, but with following code, I get a Bad Request:

```
withRest(uri: "http://api.sandbox.inrix.com") {
    def resp = get(path : '/Traffic/Inrix.ashx',
    contentType : TEXT,
    headers : [Accept : 'application/xml'],
    query : [Action:'FindRoute'])
    if (resp.status == 200) {
        println "SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

As you can see Im using the REST Plugin for Grails. I get a BAD REQUEST. SO I used cURL and found out, that they send a BAD REQUEST, but send the result, too. How can I get the result, even when get A BAD REQUEST with the REST-Plugin?

Greetings

Comment: The resp object didn't return the content? Just remove the if resp.status == 200 and print all data from resp.